# Phonegap - Loosing app control after PHP form submit

Tags: php, forms, cordova

I´m developing an APP with Phonegap were I submit a form using PHP.

Everything works well but after the sorm submition, I lost the APP control. I only get a white page (or some message defined by php file) but can´t return to the APP screen.

Is ther any solution for that?

I just have a html form action='file.php' method='post' but I'm loosing app control after form submit.

Comment: you need to use AJAX. The default action of `form.submit()` is to post the results to the current page by default.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using automatic form submit, use AJAX call to the `file.php` like this:

```
jQuery.post('file.php', { param1: 'val', param2: 'val2' });
```